# Question is being accepted from blocked users?

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, post-ban

When I try posting questions from my PC, it says *you are blocked and you cannot post question*.
But when I post questions from my mobile application, Stack Overflow accepts them. What is the reason for this?

**Note:**
Actually my account is banned from asking question. But my android application allows me to post question.

Comment: Probably someone who shares your ip address has been being naughty. Are you posting from somewhere with a shared ip between many users (such as a university)

Comment: When you're on mobile are you using the same WiFi network or are you somewhere else (or not using WiFi)? Your IP range has probably been banned, not your account.

Comment: Re edit: that is interesting, this sounds like a bug with the android app in that case

Comment: Well, a bug with the API more likely. What's the mantra? *Never trust the client*.

Comment: Are you by any chance using a different SO account in the mobile app?

Comment: absolutely not...

Comment: Just curious, if you know you're blocked for asking poor-quality questions, why would you use this to post more poor-quality questions? You just dug the hole a little bit deeper. Credit for reporting the bug though, I guess.

Comment: @BilltheLizard i don't think my questions are poor. I asked why safari is not supporting force reload option for loading javascripts? i pressed ctrl + f5 it didn't work in my browser , so i asked it. is this a poor question?

Comment: @KarthikSurianarayanan is this really related to programming? [SU] seems to be a better place for this question.

Comment: @JanDvorak this is related to scripts rite? which will be downloaded into our browser. So i tagged browsers and scripting languages. So someone related to that must know it rite..

Comment: @KarthikSurianarayanan No. Questions about _managing_ scripts are not programming-related. Questions about _making_ scripts are on-topic on [SO].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out there was a bug in checking question bans.

It actually affected both the API (which the android app uses) and the website, but it was considerably easier to hit on the API.

This was fixed in the latest deploy.